# TypeScript - void function passes as a a plain object, why?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why does a void function pass as a plain object? Is there a good reason for this, or is it a bug?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgNgQwJYDsDyAjAVhAxsKAXigG8oBtAawhAC4oBnYAJ1QHMBdehFEKAXwDcAKGG4A9iiZQAZuPFEoACgBuCOAFcI9eMnTY8wAJREAfKQGiJUgivFIAJgDEU9JScLm7jxe7MWhUQB6IKgAUWZmcWYoBAYoCAAPSHwIB2E5cSUZdQYIIxFMpQBmAoz5JQByYAgmSrLyhSUyGqZ6Fi0BExCocUooAFoE5MM0qA0GBDYIUSLvZxQCqB6AdQALPgdxWqgkAhRxAhYkNmmYngTI6IB%20IA)

```
type PlainObject = { [key: string]: any };

const foo = (value: PlainObject) => { }

const voidFn: () => void = () => { };

// Error as expected
foo(false);
foo(3);
foo('test');

foo ({ test: true }) // ok - expected usage

foo(voidFn); // Why does it not trigger an error?
```

The problem occurs only if the value is `any`. If it was `{ [key: string]: string };` for instance, the error would occur.

Comment: Almost everything in JavaScript is an object. In fact, only six things are not objects. They are — null , undefined , strings, numbers, boolean, and symbols. These are called primitive values or primitive types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are objects.

```js
const f = () => null;
const o = {};

console.log(f instanceof Object);
console.log(o instanceof Object);
```

Since every property of the PlainObject can have any value, it doesn't matter what properties the function has.

Comment: Makes sense. For some reason, I thought TypeScript would abstract that away in the types, but I see how even a `(() => { }).name` is a valid operation, so it has to be that way.